# A good and fast way to check if a JSON object contains certain values

Tags: javascript, json

I am looking for direct way of checking if the JSON I recieve from my backend holds the value i need without throwing an exception or making a for loop of `if`-statements.

I would like it to look something like this:

```
success = function(requestBody, xhr, options){
    jsonObj = JSON.parse(requestBody);
    if (!json.path.to.item.is.very.deep[0].really[3]){
        responseErrorHandler(requestBody, xhr, options)
    }
    // More Code here
}
```

This code obviously does not work because if I.E. the json object does not have the `item` object and error is throw and the code stops.

I can make a `for`-loop and parse the json but i like to see a shortcut.

Comment: There is no shortcut, you have to know what you're getting, or check each property, as in `if ( 'path' in json && 'to' in json.path && 'item' in json.path.to ... )`

Comment: @adeneo that would be impossible since the path is dynamic

Comment: So you have no idea what you're getting! What sort of service would serve something like that ?

Comment: I guess you can use `indexOf` - as `var a = {b: 5}; JSON.stringify(a).indexOf('\"b\"');` to determine if your property exists :| Seems ugly though. And not really wise, looking back at it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans i rather make a for loop

Comment: @adeneo You can never trust if an external service is going to return what you want. It might not be there at all, or it may experience some fault.

Comment: @Funonly, why? either way if it doesnt exist you need to do some error handling, using a for loop would just take up more execution time (albeit small, it would still be more than a try catch)

Answer (score 1):

An error is thrown - it's a good thing, you can handle it! Wrap the attempt to access the value (and only that line, to avoid catching unrelated errors) in try-catch, for example:

```
try {
    var x = json.path.to.item.is.very.deep[0].really[3];
} catch(e) {
    // ... handle failure... 
    return;
}
if (typeof x !== "number") { // or whatever you need
    // ... handle failure...
    return;
}
// handle success
```

Comment: Catching errors like this is what i want to prevent

Comment: @Funonly why wouldn't you want an error?  What if your code was actually trying to access the wrong value in the namespace and no error event occurred?

Comment: @jungy That is what this check if for, to see if the right value is used.